# Python - RecursionError is inconsistently thrown

Tags: python, recursion

Why does Python throw a RecursionError on line 10 but not on line 13?

```
def fib(n, a = [0,1]):
    if len(a) > n:
        return a[n]
    a.append(fib(n - 1, a) + fib(n - 2, a))
    return a[n]


def main():
    x = 998
    print(fib(x)) # RecursionError

    for i in range(1000):
        print(fib(i)) # No Error

main()
```

Comment: Not related, but watch out for that [mutable default argument](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/) it's a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i wasn't aware of the way python handles these, thanks!

Comment: When you loop through the integers in ascending order, each call to `fib()` only has to recurse one level deep, because those two lower values are already in your cache.  There's really no limit to how high you can go.  But if you ask for the `fib()` of a large number to start, it's recursing all the way down to 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking further into this, it looks like the previously mentioned mutable default argument treatment by python is actually the reason behind this. Instead of creating a new list every time the function is called, the list is created once when the function is defined.

Here is a function exploiting this feature, so that calling fib(998) doesn't throw the RecursionError:

```
def fib(n, a = [0,1]):
    if len(a) > n:
        return a[n]
    while len(a) <= n:
        a.append(fib(len(a) - 1) + fib(len(a) - 2))
    return a[n]
```